# Xamarin.Forms - How was slider ValueChanged event raised?

Tags: c#, event-handling, xamarin.forms

Is there an efficient way to determine if a `Xamarin.Forms.ValueChangedEventArgs` event was raised by user input or a programatic update?

I have a slider created in XAML and I need to make sure that the code in the event handler is only executed if the slider's value was changed by the user, and do nothing if the value was changed programatically.

Basically, I'm looking for a Xamarin.Forms equivalent of the `SeekBar.ProgressChangedEventArgs.FromUser` property in Xamarin.Android.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Do you initialize the value anywhere when the program starts?  Perhaps that is what is raising the event.  You can put a breakpoint inside the event handler and then inspect the call stack to see where the change came from.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I'm purposefully changing the value of the slider programmatically at different points, but I want the event handler to ignore those. The event handler should only respond when the user changes the slider by manually sliding it.

Comment: The only way I know to do that is to set a bool just before you programmatically change them, then check for the bool inside the event handler.

Comment: I thought about that, but I'm not sure how well it will work for me in this situation because the slider is actually a progress bar for an audio player I'm building. Its value is updated programmatically every second, but the user still needs to be able to move the slider to seek to different parts of the audio.

Comment: The fact that you're using ValueChangedEventArgs tells me that you're not doing proper data binding, which is why you're having this problem in the first place. Even if you're not doing proper MVVM you can still bind your view objects to fields in a view-model-like data structure, at which point you know exactly whether or not you've changed it manually.

Comment: @MarkFeldman I appreciate the input, but could you elaborate a little bit? I'm fairly new. How would I know exactly whether or not it's been changed manually?

Comment: @Jonathan elaboration in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of MVVM is that the property your slider binds to should represent the slider position and nothing else. As far as the rest of your view model logic code is concerned the slider property *IS* the slider. You wouldn't subclass a whole control just to determine where its value was being set from because that logic is much easier to do in the code that uses your control. MVVM isn't any different, i.e. putting that kind of logic inside a property that your view control is bound to breaks the pattern because the property should have a 1:1 relationship with the control property.

From your description it sounds like you're trying to do something like this:

```
public int SliderPos
{
    set
    {
        if (valueChangedManually()) // <-- magic function
            ManualChangeFunction();
    }
    // ... etc ...
}

void ChangeSliderPosManually()
{
    SliderPos = 100;
}
```

If so then you need to instead be doing this:

```
public int SliderPos
{
    set
    // ... etc ...
}

void ChangeSliderPosManually()
{
    ManualChangeFunction();
    SliderPos = 100;
}
```

The result is the same, but the logic is handled by the calling code instead. If at any time the value of SliderPos spontaneously changes and you haven't called ManualChangeFunction then you know it must have been triggered by the slider control.

If you really do need to know when a change is the result of the slider vs code then it is possible to add behaviors to the control itself that send notifications back to your view model layer, but that gets a bit complex and in the 10 years or so I've been developing MVVM I can't think of a single time I've ever seen a genuine need to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old post it still holds relevance. The reason is that I recently develop a music player app. When I use Xamarin.Forms `slider` it raises the `ValueChanged` event, whether the value changed manually by `User` or `programmatically`.

The Solution is to use [xamarin-range-slider](https://github.com/halkar/xamarin-range-slider). The Nuget is available for xamarin forms as well as native projects. It have events `UpperValueChanged` and `LowerValueChanged`. These events are raised when the `User` drags the slider. They did not fire on programmatic change of slider value.